# How to name partitions using fdisk?

Tags: linux, unix, virtual-machine, archlinux

I have to create a ArchLinux VM partitionate in 4 subpartitions :

- A 9go "root" subpartition
- A 5go "home" subpartition
- A 400mo non-journalized "boot" subpartition
- A 500mo "swap" subpartition

I managed to mount ArchLinux and tagged boot subpartition but now i'm lost... How i'm supposed to name the partitions with fdisk ?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux filesystems are generally labeled at the time of formating. For example:
Code:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda3 -l Gentoo
mkswap /dev/sda4 -L Swap
mkfs.reiser /dev/sda2 -L Slackware
```

The -[L|l] assigns a label to the partition.